# iOS App Recognizing The Day Of The Week

Tags: ios7, dayofweek

I have a question: I am building an app that shows my lessons on every day of the week. I would like to recognize the day of the week, and then display that in my label (Monday, Tuesday untill Friday). I dont know how to do this.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the NSDate class?

Comment: Thankyou, I didn't know what to search for but I found it. Indeed the NSDate.